# Как связать кассу, БД на локальном компе и БД на сайте?

Tags: сеть, база-данных

Задача такая:
На локальной машине хранится БД клиентов. Она должна периодически (при изменениях, видимо) копироваться на хостинг(там MySQL).
Вторая часть. У клиентов есть карточки (магнитные или со штрих кодами), которыми можно расплачиваться. Есть касса. Нужно, чтобы при считывании карты, определенная сумма списывалась со счета в БД.

Очень слабо представляю, как это организовывать. Есть ли готовое ПО для этого?
Можете посоветовать чего-нибудь стоящее?

Comment: А почему БД так распределена, разве нет возможности создать централизованную БД?

Comment: Вы хотите репликацию наверное? Что б были две распределенно зеркальные базы?

Comment: М... Есть человек, который истово желает ,чтобы основная БД была на локальном компе и только копировалась на сайт (чтобы зарегистрированные пользователи с картой могли через этот сайт смотреть сколько у них денег и т.д.)Основная проблема, как данные с компа передавать на сайт.

Comment: Да не на сайт наверное,а на хостинг где сайт работает, если так то делайте репликацию, манов полно, только не в открытом виде а по vpn какому нибудь.

Comment: В чем проблем прямого подключения к БД на хостинге, Вы боитесь, что время отклика может быть большим? К репликации нужно обращаться в последнюю очередь.

Comment: "К репликации нужно обращаться в последнюю очередь" требуются аргументы.

Comment: Есть вероятность того, что инет может внезапно пропасть. Тогда не будет доступа к базе.

Comment: Есть вероятность того, что инет может внезапно пропасть. Тогда не будет доступа к сайту. Тогда вообще ничего не будет) Если у вас репликация то по крайней мере у вас на момент отключения инета будет две зеркальные базы. При его появление они до зеркалируются за короткий промежуток времени. Это зависит от объема данных и ширины инета.

Comment: Если проблемы с инетом (это вообще плохо очень), тогда да - репликация. Но если нет, зачем иметь две БД, не понимаю. Реплкицация - лишняя нагрузка и все это понимают. Опять же, лишние действия по синхронизации данных на системном уровне.

Comment: вообще высовывать кассовую БД в инет это вообще очень плохая затея! очень!  во поводу как это сделать -- я бы для сайта сделал отделюную табличку с данными карт клиентов и кроном бы синкал только нужные поля туда. просто select на локальной базе, insert или update на базе сайта. делов на "10 минут" =)

Answer (score 4):

[Master-Slave репликация в MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html).

Comment: @eugene "Page not found".

Comment: Репликация ещё хороша тем, что данные дублируются - если вирус пожрёт локальный комп и бэкапов нет, то на сайте будет самая свежая копия + бэкапы провайдера.

Answer (score 1):

По описанию не очень понятно, что за карточки и что за сумма списывается со счета в БД. Откуда берутся деньги на счете клиента? Важна вся постановка задачи. Репликация не нужна - нужна простая выгрузка на сайт. Он уже есть? А организовать выгрузку можно через текстовый файл (судя по всему - данные плоские, т.е. одной таблицы будет достаточно).Вопросов очень много. Например, должен ли видеть клиент историю операций? Сайт уже существует? Какие взаиморасчеты предполагается вести?

Вторую часть просто написать на 1С - там есть драйверы для работы со считывателями магнитных карт и штрихкодов. А можно и на том же php с MySQLе на сервере, ежели привяжете драйверы.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще высовывать кассовую БД в инет это вообще очень плохая затея! Очень!
По поводу как это сделать -- я бы для сайта сделал отдельную табличку с данными карт клиентов и кроном бы синкал только нужные поля туда. Просто `select` на локальной базе, `insert` или `update` на базе сайта. Делов на "10 минут" =) можно даже просто выгружать в текстовый файл и импортом обычным ее загружать обратно. реализаций море же.

Рассуждения про вирусы вообще странная штука :) Хотя может про бэкапы никто не в курсе...

Comment: > высовывать кассовую БД в инет это вообще очень плохая затея!Лучше держать всё в запароленном архиве в Truecrypt контейнере, и не включать комп, чтобы по колебаниями нагрузки на сеть питания зелёные человечки с погонами не считали инфу. : )По опыту, увлекающиеся 1С, случается, не бэкапят и ловят вирусы.

Comment: ну я серьезно, такие данные лучше не высовывать) к тому же гонять туда кучу данных, которая нафиг никому не нужна на сайте -- тоже бред) а с репликацией можно еще долго промучаться, особенно если много данных)  по опыту, в курсе, а если бекапять, то часто на туже машину где база, отчего смысл бекапа существенно уменьшается)))) избавились от этого перенеся базу на линукс db2 :)

Comment: Ну, я условно сказал, что базу нужно дублировать в инет. Я и предполагал передавать только некоторые сведения. Сложность в том, что я не представляю, как осуществлять передачу.

Comment: сохраняете в какойто файл нужные данные, можно просто mysqldump можно какуюто свою структуру и потом ипортируете в нужное место.